# All executors dead MinHash LSH PySpark approxSimilarityJoin self-join on EMR cluster

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, garbage-collection, amazon-emr, minhash

I run into problems when calling Spark's MinHashLSH's approxSimilarityJoin on a dataframe of (name_id, name) combinations.

**A summary of the problem I try to solve:**

I  have a dataframe of around 30 million unique (name_id, name) combinations for company names. Some of those names refer to the same company, but are (i) either misspelled, and/or (ii) include additional names. Performing fuzzy string matching for every combination is not possible. To reduce the number of fuzzy string matching combinations, I use MinHashLSH in Spark. My intended approach is to use a approxSimilarityJoin (self-join) with a relatively large Jaccard threshold, such that I am able to run a fuzzy matching algorithm on the matched combinations to further improve the disambiguation.

**A summary of the steps I took:**

1. Used CountVectorizer to create a vector of character counts for every name,
2. Used MinHashLSH and its approxSimilarityJoin with the following settings:

   - numHashTables=100
   - threshold=0.3 (Jaccard threshold for approxSimilarityJoin)
3. After the approxSimilarityJoin, I remove duplicate combinations (for which holds that there exists a matched combination (i,j) and (j,i), then I remove (j,i))
4. After removing the duplicate combinations, I run a fuzzy string matching algorithm using the FuzzyWuzzy package to reduce the number of records and improve the disambiguation of the names.
5. Eventually I run a connectedComponents algorithm on the remaining edges (i,j) to match which company names belong together.

**Part of code used:**

```
    id_col = 'id'
    name_col = 'name'
    num_hastables = 100
    max_jaccard = 0.3
    fuzzy_threshold = 90
    fuzzy_method = fuzz.token_set_ratio

    # Calculate edges using minhash practices
    edges = MinHashLSH(inputCol='vectorized_char_lst', outputCol='hashes', numHashTables=num_hastables).\
        fit(data).\
        approxSimilarityJoin(data, data, max_jaccard).\
        select(col('datasetA.'+id_col).alias('src'),
               col('datasetA.clean').alias('src_name'),
               col('datasetB.'+id_col).alias('dst'),
               col('datasetB.clean').alias('dst_name')).\
        withColumn('comb', sort_array(array(*('src', 'dst')))).\
        dropDuplicates(['comb']).\
        rdd.\
        filter(lambda x: fuzzy_method(x['src_name'], x['dst_name']) >= fuzzy_threshold if x['src'] != x['dst'] else False).\
        toDF().\
        drop(*('src_name', 'dst_name', 'comb'))
```

**Explain plan of `edges`**

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) HashAggregate(keys=[datasetA#232, datasetB#263], functions=[])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(datasetA#232, datasetB#263, 200)
   +- *(4) HashAggregate(keys=[datasetA#232, datasetB#263], functions=[])
      +- *(4) Project [datasetA#232, datasetB#263]
         +- *(4) BroadcastHashJoin [entry#233, hashValue#234], [entry#264, hashValue#265], Inner, BuildRight, (UDF(datasetA#232.vectorized_char_lst, datasetB#263.vectorized_char_lst) < 0.3)
            :- *(4) Project [named_struct(id, id#10, name, name#11, clean, clean#90, char_lst, char_lst#95, vectorized_char_lst, vectorized_char_lst#107, hashes, hashes#225) AS datasetA#232, entry#233, hashValue#234]
            :  +- *(4) Filter isnotnull(hashValue#234)
            :     +- Generate posexplode(hashes#225), [id#10, name#11, clean#90, char_lst#95, vectorized_char_lst#107, hashes#225], false, [entry#233, hashValue#234]
            :        +- *(1) Project [id#10, name#11, clean#90, char_lst#95, vectorized_char_lst#107, UDF(vectorized_char_lst#107) AS hashes#225]
            :           +- InMemoryTableScan [char_lst#95, clean#90, id#10, name#11, vectorized_char_lst#107]
            :                 +- InMemoryRelation [id#10, name#11, clean#90, char_lst#95, vectorized_char_lst#107], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
            :                       +- *(4) Project [id#10, name#11, pythonUDF0#114 AS clean#90, pythonUDF2#116 AS char_lst#95, UDF(pythonUDF2#116) AS vectorized_char_lst#107]
            :                          +- BatchEvalPython [<lambda>(name#11), <lambda>(<lambda>(name#11)), <lambda>(<lambda>(name#11))], [id#10, name#11, pythonUDF0#114, pythonUDF1#115, pythonUDF2#116]
            :                             +- SortAggregate(key=[name#11], functions=[first(id#10, false)])
            :                                +- *(3) Sort [name#11 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :                                   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#11, 200)
            :                                      +- SortAggregate(key=[name#11], functions=[partial_first(id#10, false)])
            :                                         +- *(2) Sort [name#11 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :                                            +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(8)
            :                                               +- *(1) Filter AtLeastNNulls(n, id#10,name#11)
            :                                                  +- *(1) FileScan csv [id#10,name#11] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:<path>, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string>
            +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[1, int, false], input[2, vector, true]))
               +- *(3) Project [named_struct(id, id#10, name, name#11, clean, clean#90, char_lst, char_lst#95, vectorized_char_lst, vectorized_char_lst#107, hashes, hashes#256) AS datasetB#263, entry#264, hashValue#265]
                  +- *(3) Filter isnotnull(hashValue#265)
                     +- Generate posexplode(hashes#256), [id#10, name#11, clean#90, char_lst#95, vectorized_char_lst#107, hashes#256], false, [entry#264, hashValue#265]
                        +- *(2) Project [id#10, name#11, clean#90, char_lst#95, vectorized_char_lst#107, UDF(vectorized_char_lst#107) AS hashes#256]
                           +- InMemoryTableScan [char_lst#95, clean#90, id#10, name#11, vectorized_char_lst#107]
                                 +- InMemoryRelation [id#10, name#11, clean#90, char_lst#95, vectorized_char_lst#107], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                                       +- *(4) Project [id#10, name#11, pythonUDF0#114 AS clean#90, pythonUDF2#116 AS char_lst#95, UDF(pythonUDF2#116) AS vectorized_char_lst#107]
                                          +- BatchEvalPython [<lambda>(name#11), <lambda>(<lambda>(name#11)), <lambda>(<lambda>(name#11))], [id#10, name#11, pythonUDF0#114, pythonUDF1#115, pythonUDF2#116]
                                             +- SortAggregate(key=[name#11], functions=[first(id#10, false)])
                                                +- *(3) Sort [name#11 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                                                   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#11, 200)
                                                      +- SortAggregate(key=[name#11], functions=[partial_first(id#10, false)])
                                                         +- *(2) Sort [name#11 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                                                            +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(8)
                                                               +- *(1) Filter AtLeastNNulls(n, id#10,name#11)
                                                                  +- *(1) FileScan csv [id#10,name#11] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:<path>, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string>
```

**How `data` looks:**

```
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     id|                name|               clean|            char_lst| vectorized_char_lst|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|3633038|MURATA MACHINERY LTD|    MURATA MACHINERY|[M, U, R, A, T, A...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,5,...|
|3632811|SOCIETE ANONYME D...|SOCIETE ANONYME D...|[S, O, C, I, E, T...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,5,...|
|3632655|FUJIFILM CORPORATION|            FUJIFILM|[F, U, J, I, F, I...|(33,[3,10,12,13,2...|
|3633318|HEINE OPTOTECHNIK...|HEINE OPTOTECHNIK...|[H, E, I, N, E,  ...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,5,...|
|3633523|SUNBEAM PRODUCTS INC|    SUNBEAM PRODUCTS|[S, U, N, B, E, A...|(33,[0,1,2,4,5,6,...|
|3633300|           HIVAL LTD|               HIVAL|     [H, I, V, A, L]|(33,[2,3,10,11,21...|
|3632657|             NSK LTD|                 NSK|           [N, S, K]|(33,[5,6,16],[1.0...|
|3633240|REHABILITATION IN...|REHABILITATION IN...|[R, E, H, A, B, I...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,5,...|
|3632732|STUDIENGESELLSCHA...|STUDIENGESELLSCHA...|[S, T, U, D, I, E...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,5,...|
|3632866|ENERGY CONVERSION...|ENERGY CONVERSION...|[E, N, E, R, G, Y...|(33,[0,1,3,5,6,7,...|
|3632895|ERGENICS POWER SY...|ERGENICS POWER SY...|[E, R, G, E, N, I...|(33,[0,1,3,4,5,6,...|
|3632897| MOLI ENERGY LIMITED|         MOLI ENERGY|[M, O, L, I,  , E...|(33,[0,1,3,5,7,8,...|
|3633275| NORDSON CORPORATION|             NORDSON|[N, O, R, D, S, O...|(33,[5,6,7,8,14],...|
|3633256|  PEROXIDCHEMIE GMBH|       PEROXIDCHEMIE|[P, E, R, O, X, I...|(33,[0,3,7,8,9,11...|
|3632695|      POWER CELL INC|          POWER CELL|[P, O, W, E, R,  ...|(33,[0,1,7,8,9,10...|
|3633037|        ERGENICS INC|            ERGENICS|[E, R, G, E, N, I...|(33,[0,3,5,6,8,9,...|
|3632878|  FORD MOTOR COMPANY|          FORD MOTOR|[F, O, R, D,  , M...|(33,[1,4,7,8,13,1...|
|3632573|    SAFT AMERICA INC|        SAFT AMERICA|[S, A, F, T,  , A...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,6,...|
|3632852|ALCAN INTERNATION...| ALCAN INTERNATIONAL|[A, L, C, A, N,  ...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,5,...|
|3632698|   KRUPPKOPPERS GMBH|        KRUPPKOPPERS|[K, R, U, P, P, K...|(33,[0,6,7,8,12,1...|
|3633150|ALCAN INTERNATION...| ALCAN INTERNATIONAL|[A, L, C, A, N,  ...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,5,...|
|3632761|AMERICAN TELEPHON...|AMERICAN TELEPHON...|[A, M, E, R, I, C...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,5,...|
|3632757|HITACHI KOKI COMP...|        HITACHI KOKI|[H, I, T, A, C, H...|(33,[1,2,3,4,7,9,...|
|3632836|HUGHES AIRCRAFT C...|     HUGHES AIRCRAFT|[H, U, G, H, E, S...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,6,...|
|3633152|            SOSY INC|                SOSY|        [S, O, S, Y]|(33,[6,7,18],[2.0...|
|3633052|HAMAMATSU PHOTONI...|HAMAMATSU PHOTONI...|[H, A, M, A, M, A...|(33,[1,2,3,4,5,6,...|
|3633450|       AKZO NOBEL NV|          AKZO NOBEL|[A, K, Z, O,  , N...|(33,[0,1,2,5,7,10...|
|3632713| ELTRON RESEARCH INC|     ELTRON RESEARCH|[E, L, T, R, O, N...|(33,[0,1,2,4,5,6,...|
|3632533|NEC ELECTRONICS C...|     NEC ELECTRONICS|[N, E, C,  , E, L...|(33,[0,1,3,4,5,6,...|
|3632562| TARGETTI SANKEY SPA| TARGETTI SANKEY SPA|[T, A, R, G, E, T...|(33,[0,1,2,3,4,5,...|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 30 rows
```

**Hardware used:**

1. Master node: m5.2xlarge
   8 vCore, 32 GiB memory, EBS only storage
   EBS Storage:128 GiB
2. Slave nodes (10x): m5.4xlarge
   16 vCore, 64 GiB memory, EBS only storage
   EBS Storage:500 GiB

**Spark-submit settings used:**

```
spark-submit --master yarn --conf "spark.executor.instances=40" --conf "spark.default.parallelism=640" --conf "spark.shuffle.partitions=2000" --conf "spark.executor.cores=4" --conf "spark.executor.memory=14g" --conf "spark.driver.memory=14g" --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=14g" --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false" --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11 run_disambiguation.py
```

**Task errors from Web UI**

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 21 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Slave lost
```

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 31 exited unrelated to the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1590592506722_0001_02_000002 on host: ip-172-31-47-180.eu-central-1.compute.internal. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node.
```

**(Part of) executor logs:**

```
20/05/27 16:29:09 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (25  times so far)
20/05/27 16:29:13 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (26  times so far)
20/05/27 16:29:15 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (28  times so far)
20/05/27 16:29:17 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (0  time so far)
20/05/27 16:29:28 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (27  times so far)
20/05/27 16:29:28 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (26  times so far)
20/05/27 16:29:33 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (29  times so far)
20/05/27 16:29:38 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (1  time so far)
20/05/27 16:29:42 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (27  times so far)
20/05/27 16:29:46 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (28  times so far)
20/05/27 16:29:53 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (30  times so far)
20/05/27 16:29:57 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (2  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:00 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (28  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:05 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (29  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:10 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (31  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:15 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (3  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:19 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (29  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:22 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (30  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:29 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (32  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:32 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (4  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:39 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (31  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:39 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (30  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:46 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (33  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:47 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (5  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:55 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (32  times so far)
20/05/27 16:30:59 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (31  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:03 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (34  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:06 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (6  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:13 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (33  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:14 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (32  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:22 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (35  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:24 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (7  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:30 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (34  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:32 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (33  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:41 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (36  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:44 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (8  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:47 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (35  times so far)
20/05/27 16:31:48 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (34  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:02 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (37  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:03 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (9  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:04 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (36  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:08 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (35  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:19 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (38  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:20 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (37  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:21 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (10  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:26 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (36  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:37 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (39  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:37 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (11  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:38 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (38  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:45 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (37  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:51 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (40  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:56 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (12  times so far)
20/05/27 16:32:58 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (39  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:03 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (38  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:08 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (41  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:13 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (13  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:15 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (40  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:20 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (39  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:26 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (42  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:30 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (41  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:31 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (14  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:36 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (40  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:46 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1992.0 MB to disk (43  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:47 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (42  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:51 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (15  times so far)
20/05/27 16:33:54 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (41  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:03 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1992.0 MB to disk (43  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:04 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 146 spilling sort data of 1992.0 MB to disk (44  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:08 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (16  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:14 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (42  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:16 INFO PythonUDFRunner: Times: total = 774701, boot = 3, init = 10, finish = 774688
20/05/27 16:34:21 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 147 spilling sort data of 1992.0 MB to disk (44  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:22 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (17  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:30 INFO PythonUDFRunner: Times: total = 773372, boot = 2, init = 9, finish = 773361
20/05/27 16:34:32 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1992.0 MB to disk (43  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:39 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (18  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:46 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 89 spilling sort data of 1992.0 MB to disk (44  times so far)
20/05/27 16:34:52 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (19  times so far)
20/05/27 16:35:01 INFO PythonUDFRunner: Times: total = 776905, boot = 3, init = 11, finish = 776891
20/05/27 16:35:05 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (20  times so far)
20/05/27 16:35:19 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (21  times so far)
20/05/27 16:35:35 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (22  times so far)
20/05/27 16:35:52 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (23  times so far)
20/05/27 16:36:10 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (24  times so far)
20/05/27 16:36:29 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (25  times so far)
20/05/27 16:36:47 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (26  times so far)
20/05/27 16:37:06 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (27  times so far)
20/05/27 16:37:25 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (28  times so far)
20/05/27 16:37:44 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (29  times so far)
20/05/27 16:38:03 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (30  times so far)
20/05/27 16:38:22 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (31  times so far)
20/05/27 16:38:41 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (32  times so far)
20/05/27 16:38:59 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (33  times so far)
20/05/27 16:39:19 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (34  times so far)
20/05/27 16:39:39 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (35  times so far)
20/05/27 16:39:58 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (36  times so far)
20/05/27 16:40:18 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (37  times so far)
20/05/27 16:40:38 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (38  times so far)
20/05/27 16:40:57 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (39  times so far)
20/05/27 16:41:16 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (40  times so far)
20/05/27 16:41:35 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (41  times so far)
20/05/27 16:41:55 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1988.0 MB to disk (42  times so far)
20/05/27 16:42:19 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1992.0 MB to disk (43  times so far)
20/05/27 16:42:41 INFO ShuffleExternalSorter: Thread 145 spilling sort data of 1992.0 MB to disk (44  times so far)
20/05/27 16:42:59 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
20/05/27 16:42:59 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
20/05/27 16:42:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/05/27 16:42:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1590592506722_0001/spark-73af8e3b-f428-47d4-9e13-fed4e19cc2cd
```

```
2020-05-27T16:41:16.336+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-27T16:41:16.336+0000: [ParNew: 272234K->242K(305984K), 0.0094375 secs] 9076907K->8804915K(13188748K), 0.0094895 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2020-05-27T16:41:34.686+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-27T16:41:34.686+0000: [ParNew: 272242K->257K(305984K), 0.0084179 secs] 9076915K->8804947K(13188748K), 0.0084840 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2020-05-27T16:41:35.145+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-27T16:41:35.145+0000: [ParNew: 272257K->1382K(305984K), 0.0095541 secs] 9076947K->8806073K(13188748K), 0.0096080 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2020-05-27T16:41:55.077+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-27T16:41:55.077+0000: [ParNew: 273382K->2683K(305984K), 0.0097177 secs] 9078073K->8807392K(13188748K), 0.0097754 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2020-05-27T16:41:55.513+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-27T16:41:55.513+0000: [ParNew: 274683K->3025K(305984K), 0.0093345 secs] 9079392K->8807734K(13188748K), 0.0093892 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2020-05-27T16:42:05.481+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-27T16:42:05.481+0000: [ParNew: 275025K->4102K(305984K), 0.0092950 secs] 9079734K->8808830K(13188748K), 0.0093464 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2020-05-27T16:42:18.711+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-27T16:42:18.711+0000: [ParNew: 276102K->2972K(305984K), 0.0098928 secs] 9080830K->8807700K(13188748K), 0.0099510 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2020-05-27T16:42:36.493+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-27T16:42:36.493+0000: [ParNew: 274972K->3852K(305984K), 0.0094324 secs] 9079700K->8808598K(13188748K), 0.0094897 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2020-05-27T16:42:40.880+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-27T16:42:40.880+0000: [ParNew: 275852K->2568K(305984K), 0.0111794 secs] 9080598K->8807882K(13188748K), 0.0112352 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
Heap
 par new generation   total 305984K, used 261139K [0x0000000440000000, 0x0000000454c00000, 0x0000000483990000)
  eden space 272000K,  95% used [0x0000000440000000, 0x000000044fc82cf8, 0x00000004509a0000)
  from space 33984K,   7% used [0x00000004509a0000, 0x0000000450c220a8, 0x0000000452ad0000)
  to   space 33984K,   0% used [0x0000000452ad0000, 0x0000000452ad0000, 0x0000000454c00000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 12882764K, used 8805314K [0x0000000483990000, 0x0000000795e63000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 77726K, capacity 79553K, committed 79604K, reserved 1118208K
  class space    used 10289K, capacity 10704K, committed 10740K, reserved 1048576K
```

[Screenshot of executors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsKzB.png)

**What I tried:**

- Changing `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`
- Changing `spark.default.parallelism`
- Repartition the dataframe

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Thijs

Answer (score 5):

The answer of @lokk3r really helped me in the right direction here. However, there were some other things that I had to do before I was able to run the program without errors. I will share them to help people out that are having similar problems:

- First of all, I used `NGrams` as @lokk3r suggested instead of just single characters to avoid extreme data skew inside the MinHashLSH algorithm. When using 4-grams, `data` looks like:

```
+------------------------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                          name|     id|                         clean|                   ng_char_lst|           vectorized_char_lst|
+------------------------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|     SOCIETE ANONYME DITE SAFT|3632811|     SOCIETE ANONYME DITE SAFT|[  S O C, S O C I, O C I E,...|(1332,[64,75,82,84,121,223,...|
|          MURATA MACHINERY LTD|3633038|              MURATA MACHINERY|[  M U R, M U R A, U R A T,...|(1332,[55,315,388,437,526,5...|
|HEINE OPTOTECHNIK GMBH AND ...|3633318|    HEINE OPTOTECHNIK GMBH AND|[  H E I, H E I N, E I N E,...|(1332,[23,72,216,221,229,34...|
|          FUJIFILM CORPORATION|3632655|                      FUJIFILM|[  F U J, F U J I, U J I F,...|(1332,[157,179,882,1028],[1...|
|          SUNBEAM PRODUCTS INC|3633523|              SUNBEAM PRODUCTS|[  S U N, S U N B, U N B E,...|(1332,[99,137,165,175,187,1...|
| STUDIENGESELLSCHAFT KOHLE MBH|3632732| STUDIENGESELLSCHAFT KOHLE MBH|[  S T U, S T U D, T U D I,...|(1332,[13,14,23,25,43,52,57...|
|REHABILITATION INSTITUTE OF...|3633240|REHABILITATION INSTITUTE OF...|[  R E H, R E H A, E H A B,...|(1332,[20,44,51,118,308,309...|
|           NORDSON CORPORATION|3633275|                       NORDSON|[  N O R, N O R D, O R D S,...|(1332,[45,88,582,1282],[1.0...|
|     ENERGY CONVERSION DEVICES|3632866|     ENERGY CONVERSION DEVICES|[  E N E, E N E R, N E R G,...|(1332,[54,76,81,147,202,224...|
|           MOLI ENERGY LIMITED|3632897|                   MOLI ENERGY|[  M O L, M O L I, O L I  ,...|(1332,[438,495,717,756,1057...|
|    ERGENICS POWER SYSTEMS INC|3632895|        ERGENICS POWER SYSTEMS|[  E R G, E R G E, R G E N,...|(1332,[6,10,18,21,24,35,375...|
|                POWER CELL INC|3632695|                    POWER CELL|[  P O W, P O W E, O W E R,...|(1332,[6,10,18,35,126,169,3...|
|            PEROXIDCHEMIE GMBH|3633256|                 PEROXIDCHEMIE|[  P E R, P E R O, E R O X,...|(1332,[326,450,532,889,1073...|
|            FORD MOTOR COMPANY|3632878|                    FORD MOTOR|[  F O R, F O R D, O R D  ,...|(1332,[156,158,186,200,314,...|
|                  ERGENICS INC|3633037|                      ERGENICS|[  E R G, E R G E, R G E N,...|(1332,[375,642,812,866,1269...|
|              SAFT AMERICA INC|3632573|                  SAFT AMERICA|[  S A F, S A F T, A F T  ,...|(1332,[498,552,1116],[1.0,1...|
|   ALCAN INTERNATIONAL LIMITED|3632598|           ALCAN INTERNATIONAL|[  A L C, A L C A, L C A N,...|(1332,[20,434,528,549,571,7...|
|             KRUPPKOPPERS GMBH|3632698|                  KRUPPKOPPERS|[  K R U, K R U P, R U P P,...|(1332,[664,795,798,1010,114...|
|       HUGHES AIRCRAFT COMPANY|3632752|               HUGHES AIRCRAFT|[  H U G, H U G H, U G H E,...|(1332,[605,632,705,758,807,...|
|AMERICAN TELEPHONE AND TELE...|3632761|AMERICAN TELEPHONE AND TELE...|[  A M E, A M E R, M E R I,...|(1332,[19,86,91,126,128,134...|
+------------------------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Note that I added leading and trailing white spaces on the names, to make sure that the order of words in the name does not matter for the `NGrams`: `'XX YY'` has 3-grams `'XX ', 'X Y', ' YY'`, while `'YY XX'` has 3-grams `'YY ', 'Y X', ' XX'`. This means that both share 0 out of 6 unique `NGrams`. If we use leading and trailing white spaces: `' XX YY '` has 3-grams `' XX', 'XX ', 'X Y', ' YY', 'YY '`, while `' YY XX '` has 3-grams `' YY', 'YY ', 'Y X', ' XX', 'XX '`. This means both share 4 out of 6 unique `NGrams`. This means that there is much more probability that both records end in the same bucket during MinHashLSH.

- I experimented with different values of `n` - the input parameter for `NGrams`. I found that both `n=2` and `n=3` still gives so much data skew that a few Spark jobs take way too long while others are done within seconds. So you end up waiting forever before the program continues. I now use `n=4`, and that still gives substantial skew but it is workable.
- To reduce the effects of the data skew even more, I used some additional filtering of too (in)frequently occuring `NGrams` in the `CountVectorizer` method of Spark. I have set `minDF=2` such that it filters out `NGrams` that are occuring in only a single name. I did this because you cannot match those names based on a `NGram` that occurs only in one name anyways. In addition, I set `maxDF=0.001` such that it filters out `NGrams` that are occuring in more than 0.1% of the names. This means for approximately 30 million names, that `NGrams` that occur more frequently than in 30000 names are filtered out. I figured that a too frequently occuring `NGram` will not provide usefull information on which names can be matched anyways.
- I reduce the number of unique names (30 million first) to 15 million by filtering out the non-Latin (extended) names. I noticed that (e.g. Arabic and Chinese) characters caused a big skew in the data as well. Since I am not primarily interested in disambiguating these company names, I disregarded them from the data set. I filtered using the following regex match:

```
re.fullmatch('[\u0020-\u007F\u00A0-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-\u024F]+'.encode(), string_to_filter.encode())
```

- This is a little bit a straight forward advise, but I ran into some problems by not seing it. Make sure you run a filter on dataset before feeding it to the `MinHashLSH` algorithm to filter out records that have no `NGrams` remaining due to the settings `minDF` and `maxDF` or just because it is a small name. Obviously this will not work for the `MinHashLSH` algorithm.
- Finally, regarding the settings of the `spark-submit` command and the hardware settings of the EMR cluster, I found that I didn't need a larger cluster as some of the answers on the forums suggested. All the above changes made the program run perfectly on a cluster with the settings as provided in my original post. Reducing the `spark.shuffle.partitions`, the `spark.driver.memory` and the `spark.driver.maxResultSize` substantially improved the running time of the program. The `spark-submit` I submitted was:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --conf "spark.executor.instances=40" --conf "spark.default.parallelism=640" --conf "spark.executor.cores=4" --conf "spark.executor.memory=12g" --conf "spark.driver.memory=8g" --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=8g" --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false" --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11 run_disambiguation.py
```

Comment: Regarding the advise on filtering out records that have no NGrams, can you please share your part of the code that you used for filtering? I filter rows that are all-zero vectors but still I get the "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Must have at least 1 non zero entry." error. I appreciate any tip on this issue. thanks

Answer (score 2):

`approxSimilarityJoin` will only parallelize well across workers if the tokens being input into MinHash are sufficiently distinct.  Since individual character tokens appear frequently across many records; include an `NGram` transformation on your character list to make the appearance of each token less frequent; this will greatly reduce data skew and will resolve memory strain.

MinHash simulates the process of creating a random permutation of your token population and selects the token in the sample set that appears first in the permutation.  Since you are using individual characters as tokens, let's say you select a MinHash seed that makes the character `e` the first in your random permutation.  In this case, every row with the letter `e` in it will have a matching MinHash and will be shuffled to the same worker for set comparison.  This will cause extreme data skew and out of memory errors.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really helpful suggestion and makes a lot of sense. I will incorporate an ```NGram``` transformation in the program and test it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on setting n? The higher n, the less skewed the data will be, correct? However, for larger n, less will also end up as a match right?

Comment: @thijsvdp I'm not sure there is a great answer for selecting n; as you described, it is a bit of a tradeoff.  I'd start with 3 or 4 and adjust based on your results.  You can somewhat offset the loss of recall from selecting a larger n by increasing numHashTables in your MinHash model.  More hash tables will take longer to process, but it will not suffer from data skew problems like a very small n.

Comment: Allright that's clear. And do you have any ideas/suggestions on the number of hashtables to use? Or is that just trial and error? Because I have been looking in many threads to find a reasonable starting point, but I did not find much. Only that there is some tradeoff between recall and computation time.

Comment: @thijsvdp it is dependent on the use case.  Think of it this way; how many ngrams do you think you would need to sample out of a record to be very confident that it would share at least 1 ngram with another record you want to compare it against?  That is the number of hash tables you should use.  For many uses of MinHash, between 3 and 5 hash tables are common.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as Ehsan where Spark would tell me that I was passing vectors with no non-zero elements to MinHashLSH, even after I set a filter to remove those rows. I would get the error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Must have at least 1 non zero entry` when running the MinHashLSH implementation described in this question.

In my case, turns out that the issue comes from the fact that I filtered out vectors with no non-zero entries using a UDF, with defaults to deterministic in nature. I had to set the UDF to be nondeterministic to ensure the proper timing of the filter in the execution plan. Here's some more info I found about the deterministic/nondeterministic nature of UDF's: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/the-recipe-of-instability-f2e914e31f5a

So to fix my issue, I ran something like the following pseudo-code:

```cv
model_cv = cv.fit(df)
df2 = model_cv.transform(df)

has_nonzeros = udf(lambda s: s.numNonzeros()>0, BooleanType()).asNondeterministic()
df2_filtered = df2.filter(has_nonzeros('vectors'))

mh = MinHashLSH(inputCol='vectors', outputCol='hashes', numHasTables=5)
model_mh = mh.fit(df2_filtered)
...
```

Comment: I've spent the last 2 hours running into this issue and `.asNondeterministic()` just solved it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed explanation.
What threshold are you using a and how are reducing false -ve?

Comment: I use the threshold 0.3 for Jaccard distance now. It is way too high for most cases. To make sure that I don't miss too much, I set it this high. I use the ```FuzzyWuzzy``` library to postprocess the matches to get more accurate matches and reduce the false-positives .